# Use private google calendar in with fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

i would like to display private google calendar with fullcalendar. HTML calendar will be available just in private network and I don't want it to be public. Is it possible with fullcalendar?

Tomas

Comment: I also need this feature. I know that in Google Domains you can give API access permissions to clients. I think that's its also possible for the Calendar API. Will let you know in few days what I found. Hope that someone else will contribute his insights.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you have Google Apps for Dmoains.

The solution is to fetch the calendar data using Google API from your server. Then serve it to fullcalendar the same way you serve events from DB and etc.

To do that, you need:

1. Create [API account](https://console.developers.google.com) with corresponding keys
2. Enable the Calendar API (same site)
3. Allow scope access at the Google Domain admin site (under advanced security)
4. DL and use [Google API client library](https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries) to fetch the data using server side